# React Redux Loading Bar not showing up

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-immutable

I have a problem with using React Redux Loading Bar.it is not showing up.I'm using immutable js, redux immutable library in root reducer.I don't get any errors. If I inspect elements tree, there is only one empty div. what mistake am I making here

**index.js**

```
import { ImmutableLoadingBar as LoadingBar} from 'react-redux-loading-bar'

class Header extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
  <header>
    <LoadingBar />
  </header>
)
}
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
import { loadingBarReducer } from 'react-redux-loading-bar'

export function rootReducer(state = routeInitialState, action) {
switch (action.type) {

case LOCATION_CHANGE:
  return state.merge({
    location: action.payload,
  });
default:
  return state;
  }
}
export default function createReducer(injectedReducers) {
  return combineReducers({
    route: rootReducer,
    language: languageProviderReducer,
    loadingBar: loadingBarReducer,
    ...injectedReducers,
   });
   }
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import createReducer from './reducers';
import { loadingBarMiddleware } from 'react-redux-loading-bar'

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}, history) {
 const middlewares = 
  [sagaMiddleware,routerMiddleware(history),loadingBarMiddleware()];

 const enhancers = [applyMiddleware(...middlewares)];


 const composeEnhancers =
process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
typeof window === 'object' &&
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
  ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
      shouldHotReload: false,
    })
  : compose;

 const store = createStore(
    createReducer(),
    fromJS(initialState),
    composeEnhancers(...enhancers),
  );

 store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;
```

Comment: What do you expect to see? Your loading bar has no properties - presumably you need to hook into some progress value, which is normally a state variable?

Comment: i dont see loading bar itself, i follow docs, it simply says mount component any where in component and it should work.

Comment: The demo code sets a `scope=`, which I think is what you are missing. There is an example on the module github page

Comment: i tried using scope ,it still doesnt show up in page,its being said that, scope is used when we use it in multiple places, for now i use only one loading bar.

Comment: ok, so there is some magic there that you haven't hooked into... If you really want to stick with using that component, I would start with a working demo (their code), and add your code chunk by chunk until it stops working

Comment: thanks.actually i want to show it when page reloads, and navigating to other pages. i use saga middleware.

Comment: Have you figured it out? When I inspect I see `<div></div>` when I should se `<LoadingBar/>` why it's not working, what causes this, damn

Comment: yes i have fixed it.

Comment: @Ashok How? I have the same issue? Please post your solution here :)

Comment: I ended up binding it manually through mapStateToProps <LoadingBar loading={this.props.loadingBar.default} /> for lib version 4.6.0... after so many years, let me know if there is a better solution lol

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue, but I was not using immutable-js. However, I'd like to post my solution anyway, maybe it'll help someone :)

So I did everything according to the instructions on the npm-page, but I missed one little detail: react-redux-loading-bar exports both the connected container "LoadingBar" and the LoadingBar component itself. (see https://github.com/mironov/react-redux-loading-bar/issues/79#issuecomment-441355249)

So make sure to import the connected container (without curly braces around LoadingBar):

```
import LoadingBar from 'react-redux-loading-bar'
```

This might be trivial for many, but maybe it'll help someone.